# PCIEx16_2 Causes Black Screen

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, asus, amdgpu-pro

I'm trying to use two RX480s with an ASUS B350-Plus motherboard running Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine when I only have one 480 plugged in to the `PCEx16_1` slot, but if I plug anything into the `PCEx16_2` slot, I get stuck at a black screen on boot. I've tried both cards in the first slot and they work fine so I know the issue is not with the the cards; it's specifically the second slot.

**Config:**

- CPU: Ryzen 3 1200
- GPU: 2x RX480s
- MB: ASUS B350-plus
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Kernel 4.13.0-32-generic)
- Graphic Driver: AMDGPU-PRO Driver Version 17.50 for Ubuntu 16.04.3

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Plugging either GPU into `PCIEx16_2`

**Expected Behavior:**

Boot into Ubuntu normally, be able to use both cards.

**Actual Behavior:**
BIOS screen displays and then screen goes black and stays that way.

Update:
Doing some digging revealed that PCIEx_16 shares lanes with SATA1. I moved the hard drive from SATA1 to SATA4 and successfully managed to get to the grub boot loader. However trying to enter the os I got the following results. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sfX.jpg

I rebooted a second time and got this after passing the bootloader 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmiPg.jpg

Comment: Hrm, do you know if this issue is specific to Linux? For example, will Windows boot fine with both cards? Also, what happens if you try to boot with only one card in the 2nd PCIe slot?

Comment: I don't know if this is specific to linux since I don't have a windows install to test it on. I think has something to do with the slot because when I plug either card into just the second slot, i experience the same problem.